# ESP32-S2 QT PY Deep Sleep Wakeup

Tags: tcp, esp32

I currently have an ESP32-S2 QT Py that I am using to send sensor data to a PC via wifi using TCP. I want to preserve battery life while not sensing, so I put it into deep sleep. I see that there are timer, pin, and touch alarms to wake it back up, but none of these work well for my design. Is there any way that I can wake up a deep sleeping ESP32-S2 with a TCP packet send from the PC server?

Comment: Maybe it’s not possible in your use case ; but why you don’t take the initiative by the sensor/esp32?

Answer (score 1):

This functionality is commonly called "wake on LAN" and is generally used, as you described, to allow a "magic" packet to wake up a sleeping or hibernating device.

In this case, no. The ESP32's wifi radio is off during deep sleep. With the radio off there's nothing active that can receive or detect a packet.

If you're trying to conserve power and maximize battery life, you need to keep the radio off as it uses quite a bit of power just to stay connected to a wifi network.

The only parts of the ESP32 that are active and available during deep sleep are the ULP ("Ultra Low Power") processor, a very limited slow processor that can perform a few I/O actions during sleep, and a small amount of static RAM associated with the real time clock. You can learn more about the ULP and what it can do in [Espressif's documentation](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-reference/system/ulp.html).